# Changing from SQL Server to Oracle database

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, oracle

I've been asked to migrate my application from using a SQL Server database to an Oracle database.

I'm getting this error:

> ORA-00942: table or view does not exist

I could be wrong, but I believe this is an issue with my statement. Is there a specific format I would need to follow connected to an oracle database over a SQL Server?

I will include my query statement:

```
namespace project1
{
    public class dbqry
    {
        private static string qry = "";


        public static DataTable gProjectCIS(string BSA_CD)
        {
            qry = string.Format(@"SELECT *
                    FROM CIS_TRANS
                    WHERE BSA_CD like '%{0}%'", BSA_CD);

            return dbcon.GetDataTable(qry, "ProjectCISConnectionString");
        }

        public static DataTable gProjectCIS()
        {
            qry = @"SELECT *
                    FROM CIS_TRANS";

            return dbcon.GetDataTable(qry, "ProjectCISConnectionString");
        }
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hello you must prefix your table with schema

```
  qry = string.Format(@"SELECT *
         FROM YourSchemaUser.CIS_TRANS <-- Fix your schema user name
         WHERE BSA_CD like '%{0}%'", BSA_CD);

  qry = @"SELECT * FROM YourSchemaUser.CIS_TRANS"; <-- Fix your schema user name
```

And Fix Package on stored procedure.

You change declaration and body, compile your package in the first time before use

Comment: Packagename would be the database its from? Also, since Im doing a gridview with update,select,delete and all those, in my default.asp page, would I need to do the same there too?

Comment: on all your objects you must define schema ad package on stored procedure

Comment: Alright, My Schema in this scenario is CIS. So it would look like CIS.CIS_TRANS . Would I as well have to change ever CIS_TRANS declaration to CIS.CIS_TRANS, or only the one on the query page?

Comment: Yes you must change declaration and body, compile your package in the first time before use

Comment: Worked out perfect, I wasnt aware of the differences I must include when changing to an oracle database @Aghilas Yakoub, thank you!

Comment: I'am happy to help you Michael

Answer (score 0):

Oracle is picky when it comes to case sensitivity.  If the table was declared with "QUOTES", you'll need to include the quotes in your query and match case.  That's probably a good start.

Answer (score 0):

Check the object names. Also check they are in the correct case.

Check that the username you are using to connect to the database have permissions over the tables/views you are trying to use. Oracle usually says that the table does not exist when you don't have the right privileges.

Comment: See http://www.mydigitallife.info/ora-00942-table-or-view-does-not-exist-oracle-error/

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you're logging into the correct schema?

Answer (score 0):

You should check whether the CIS_TRANS table has the appropraite public synonym, something like:

```
create or replace public synonym CIS_TRANS for some_user.CIS_TRANS
```

where some_user is the user which created the CIS_TRANS object.